# Split string into tuple (Upper,lower) 'ABCDefgh' . Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, split, uppercase, lowercase

```
my_string = 'ABCDefgh'
desired = ('ABCD','efgh')
```

the only way I can think of doing this is creating a for loop and then scanning through and checking each element in the string individually and adding to string and then creating the tuple . . . is there a more efficient way to do this?

it will always be in the format UPPERlower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print re.split("([A-Z]+)",my_string)[1:]
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for! i knew there was something like that

Comment: it will not work if its not the form you described "ABCdefGHI", would probably not give you the expected results for example

Comment: when i print this i get 3 values; namely, ['', 'ABCD', 'efg'] why is there an empty string in the beginning ?

Comment: i fixed it ... its because its splitting on capitals ... and before the capitals there is an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Simple way (two passes):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> my_string = 'ABCDefgh'
>>> desired = (''.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda c:c.isupper(), my_string)), ''.join(itertools.dropwhile(lambda c:c.isupper(), my_string)))
>>> desired
('ABCD', 'efgh')
```

Efficient way (one pass):

```
>>> my_string = 'ABCDefgh'
>>> uppers = []
>>> done = False
>>> i = 0
>>> while not done:
...     c = my_string[i]
...     if c.isupper():
...         uppers.append(c)
...         i += 1
...     else:
...         done = True
... 
>>> lowers = my_string[i:]
>>> desired = (''.join(uppers), lowers)
>>> desired
('ABCD', 'efgh')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I throw [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) at everything:

```
>>> my_string = 'ABCDefgh'
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [''.join(g) for k,g in groupby(my_string, str.isupper)]
['ABCD', 'efgh']
```

(A little overpowered here, but scales up to more complicated problems nicely.)

Comment: Would be problematic if `my_string = 'ABCDefGHI'`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: whether or not it'd be problematic depends upon what the OP expects.  Did I miss an example with oscillating case?

Comment: Good point. I was overcomplicating the problem like I do sometimes

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string='ABCDefg'
import re
desired = (re.search('[A-Z]+',my_string).group(0),re.search('[a-z]+',my_string).group(0))
print desired
```

Answer (score 0):

A more robust approach without using `re`

```
import string

>>> txt = "ABCeUiioualfjNLkdD"
>>> tup = (''.join([char for char in txt if char in string.ascii_uppercase]),
  ''.join([char for char in txt if char not in string.ascii_uppercase]))

>>> tup
('ABCUNLD', 'eiioualfjkd')
```

the `char not in string.ascii_uppercase` instead of `char in string.ascii_lowercase` means that you'll never lose any data in case your string has non-letters in it, which could be useful if you suddenly start having errors when this input starts being rejected 20 function calls later.